# How to implement In App Purchase Subscription Model?

Tags: ios4

I have uploaded an app to the app store, and now I want to implement In App Purchase Subscription Model. I have followed the tutorial step by step but didn't find the link to Manage In App Purchase. I am appending an image also. Please have a look and let me know where I am wrong. Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
and also I can't see this icone on my iTunesConnect Home page!
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu gotto get the Contracts in place to sell paid apps/in app purchases. Plz make sure u submit the contact, tax & bank info.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you...

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/inapppurchase/subscriptions.html

We really should thank Apple for wonderful documentation (No sarcasm intended :)

Comment: I have read lot many documents on In App Purchase but I didn't understand Why I can't see the "Mange In App Purchase" link on this page (image above). So please let me know the reason which could be behind this.